# Should developer create a different model of Login Request & Response

Tags: android, json, model, gson

I am using `gson` library in my demo android project. I want to know should I create a different model for login request & login response in `json`.

For the request I created like below

```
public class Login {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUserName() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUserName(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Creating `JSON` from login request.

```
// creating JSON using GSON library
Login mLogin = new Login();
mLogin.setUserName(userName);
mLogin.setPassword(password);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String loginJSON = gson.toJson(mLogin);
```

So here above I created a model for login request & should I create a new model of login response which again in `json` or Am I not doing following correct approach.

Comment: You don't need request models, models are built from response json. That is the magic part of GSON, because no one likes parsing out the JSON responses.

Comment: then how should I create JSON request without model how ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android

Comment: @zgc7009 please write some words in answer so that I can accept it

Comment: I think you would need a separate model, as the response may contain fields (such as a failure reason), which may not exist in the request.

Comment: @NelsonWright yes exactly so should we create model for both request & response or only response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson helps us to serialize and deserialize json objects/strings to make our coding life easier. If you want you can write your own json parser or use another json parsers such as jackson. Also you can work on pure string value of jsons because json is just a formatted string like xml representation.

Pojos for json values make coding, reading code, maintenance easier. I prefer having pojo classes for both input and output json values.(that is just a choice)

> I created a model for login request & should I create a new model of
>   login response which again in json or Am I not doing following correct
>   approach.

The answer of your question is; it's up to you. If you really need a pojo class then you should write it. If you don't then you may prefer to write it or handle json without any pojos. (By using Gson you can get/create json arrays, objects, values.)

You can see my [previous answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768137/gson-deserialize-json-of-embedded-member/25948640#25948640) to be clear.